# How to restrict record creation, updation and deletion without trigger.?

Tags: visual-workflow, validation

I have a flow which creates order and order line items from quote and quote line items if approved by manager. Once order and order line items are created i want to avoid creation, update and delete of order and order line items.
I am using validation rules to achieve this but it is restricting flow as well to create new records. So basically i want only flow to create records nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot restrict record deletion (other than by removing the object-level permission from the affected users) without a trigger, save by a clumsy indirection. If you establish a rollup field on the parent object, such as a `COUNT()` of the child objects you don't want to be deleted, you can write validation rules on the parent to prohibit changes and thereby fail any transaction that attempts to delete a child object.

However, this only works if you have a master-detail relationship and can define the criteria for the situation where deletion is not allowed in terms of fields on the parent object, which sounds like it is *not* the case here.

So to restrict deletion, you need to either change object permissions, or write a trigger, full stop.

To restrict other operations so that they're only achievable by automation, a common recommendation that you'll find in numerous examples if you search SFSE is to write a validation rule to require that any change to the object must modify (`ISCHANGED()`) a specific hidden field, on that's not shown on the page layout. The Process or Flow can modify that field to allow its changes to go through, but the user cannot.